# Which lifecycle hook to use on child component to run after parent in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

On the parent I'm running this:

```
  mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchNotesAction')
  },
components: { ChildComponent }
```

With that, the Vuex store is populated with data.

I'm assuming, therefore, by the time the child component runs, the store is already full.

In the `ChildComponent` I'm trying this

```
mounted(){
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getNotes) 
  },
```

If I log the exact same code inside the parent, after the `dispatch` it display the data. So the code (the connection) behind those lines work fine, just am I correct in assuming that I don't need to rerun the fetch (from `fetchNotesAction`) again?

I tried `created` instead of `mounted` and the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use a computed property that returns your state getter then use watch property to observe its changes in the child component :

```
computed:{
  notes(){
   return  this.$store.getters.getNotes;
   }
},
watch:{
  notes(newval,oldVal)'
    console.log(newval) 
  }
}
```